# Android app working on emulator but not real device, SharePreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, emulation

I have wrote this app for searching a ride: input the source name and display the ride in a list view that start place is same as the user source name. It works fine on Emulator but it stop working after I have pick the source name when I try to run the app on a real device.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ITEM_TITLE = "Item title";
    private static final String ITEM_SOURCE = "Source";
    private static final String ITEM_DESTINATION = "Destination";
    static int no = 0;
    static int y = 0;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment sourceAutocompleteFragment;
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment destinationAutocompleteFragment;
    PlaceObj sourcePlace = null;
    PlaceObj destination = null;
    ArrayList<PlaceObj> p = new ArrayList<PlaceObj>();
    String sourceName = "";
    String destinationName = "";
    ArrayList<Ride> rides = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView lsv_main;
    private ListAdapter mListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lsv_main = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Source
        sourceAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_source);

        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();
        sourceAutocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

        actionSource();

        //Destination
        //Source
        destinationAutocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_destination);

        typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();
        destinationAutocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

        actionDestination();


    }


    public void actionSource() {

        final ArrayList<Ride> rideTemp = new ArrayList<Ride>();

        sourceAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place place) {

                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Place:" + place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sourceName = (String) place.getName();
                Double latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                Double longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                String address = (String) place.getAddress();

                API.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRideByStartPlace(latitude, longitude, new ResponseListener() {  //get ride
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String str) {
                                super.onResponse(str);
                                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                                System.out.println(str);
                                try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
                                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);  //{}->1 object
                                    if (jsonData.has("msg")) {

                                        if (jsonData.getString("msg").equals("No exist ride with the entered start point.")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No exist ride with the entered start point.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else {  //get the ride info and store to ride Object
                                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


                                            jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                            System.out.println(jsonData);
                                            int rideId = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("rideId"));
                                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                            Date createOn = format.parse(jsonData.getString("create_on"));
                                            System.out.println(createOn);
                                            String travelDateTime = jsonData.getString("travel_start_time");
                                            int sourceId = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("source_place_id"));


                                            // String sourceName = source.getName();


                                            getPlace(sourceId, new VolleyCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccessResponse(String result) {
                                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("place", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("placeObj", "");
                                                    sourcePlace = new Gson().fromJson(json, PlaceObj.class);

                                                }
                                            });

                                            int destinationId = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("destination_place_id"));
                                            getPlace(destinationId, new VolleyCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccessResponse(String result) {
                                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("place", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("placeObj", "");
                                                    destination = new Gson().fromJson(json, PlaceObj.class);
                                                }
                                            });


                                            int seats = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("seats_offered"));
                                            String remark = jsonData.getString("remark");
                                            Ride ride = new Ride(rideId, createOn, travelDateTime, sourcePlace, destination, seats, remark, sourceId, destinationId);

                                            rideTemp.add(ride);


                                        }
                                        System.out.println("myArry " + rideTemp);
                                        showRide(rideTemp);
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                System.out.println(str);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(VolleyError error) {
                                super.onError(error);
                            }
                        }
                );

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error" + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Rides array:" + rides);

    }

    public void actionDestination() {

        final ArrayList<Ride> rideTemp = new ArrayList<Ride>();

        destinationAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place place) {

                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Place:" + place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                destinationName = (String) place.getName();
                System.out.println("rSource: " + sourceName);
                Double latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
                Double longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
                String address = (String) place.getAddress();

                API.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getRideByStartDestinationPlace(sourceName, latitude, longitude, new ResponseListener() {  //get ride
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String str) {
                                super.onResponse(str);
                                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                                System.out.println(str);
                                try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
                                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);  //{}->1 object
                                    if (jsonData.has("msg")) {

                                        if (jsonData.getString("msg").equals("No exist ride with the entered start point.")) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No exist ride with the entered start point.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    } else {  //get the ride info and store to ride Object
                                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                            jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                            System.out.println(jsonData);
                                            int rideId = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("rideId"));
                                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                            Date createOn = format.parse(jsonData.getString("create_on"));
                                            System.out.println(createOn);
                                            String travelDateTime = jsonData.getString("travel_start_time");
                                            int sourceId = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("source_place_id"));

                                            getPlace(sourceId, new VolleyCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccessResponse(String result) {
                                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("place", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("placeObj", "");
                                                    sourcePlace = new Gson().fromJson(json, PlaceObj.class);

                                                }
                                            });

                                            int destinationId = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("destination_place_id"));
                                            getPlace(destinationId, new VolleyCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccessResponse(String result) {
                                                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("place", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("placeObj", "");
                                                    destination = new Gson().fromJson(json, PlaceObj.class);
                                                }
                                            });


                                            int seats = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("seats_offered"));
                                            String remark = jsonData.getString("remark");
                                            Ride ride = new Ride(rideId, createOn, travelDateTime, sourcePlace, destination, seats, remark, sourceId, destinationId);

                                            rideTemp.add(ride);


                                        }
                                        System.out.println("myArry " + rideTemp);
                                        showRide(rideTemp);
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                System.out.println(str);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(VolleyError error) {
                                super.onError(error);
                            }
                        }
                );

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error" + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Rides array:" + rides);

    }

    public void getPlace(int id, final VolleyCallback callback) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("place", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        final PlaceObj[] placeBean = new PlaceObj[1];
        API.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getPlaceById(id, new ResponseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String str) {
                super.onResponse(str);
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;


                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(str);
                    JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    int placeId = Integer.parseInt(jsonData.getString("placeId"));
                    String name = jsonData.getString("name");
                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(jsonData.getString("latitude"));
                    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(jsonData.getString("longitude"));
                    String address = jsonData.getString("address");
                    System.out.println("address" + name);
                    PlaceObj placeObj = new PlaceObj(placeId, name, latitude, longitude, address);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(placeObj);
                    editor.putString("placeObj" + placeId, json);
                    editor.commit();
                    no++;
                    callback.onSuccessResponse(str);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(str);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VolleyError error) {
                super.onError(error);
            }
        });

    }


    public void showRide(final ArrayList<Ride> rides) {
        final String[] myarray = new String[10];
        List<Map<String, Object>> itemList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rides.size(); i++) {

            final Ride ride = rides.get(i);
            final Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            item.put(ITEM_TITLE, rides.get(i).getTravelDateTime());
            System.out.println("sourceid: " + rides.get(i).getSourceID());
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("place", MODE_PRIVATE);  //test as login info
            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("placeObj" + rides.get(i).getSourceID(), "");
            PlaceObj a = new Gson().fromJson(json, PlaceObj.class);
            String creator_id = a.getName();
            System.out.println("Name:" + creator_id);
            item.put(ITEM_SOURCE, creator_id);

            json = sharedPreferences.getString("placeObj" + rides.get(i).getDestinationID(), "");
            a = new Gson().fromJson(json, PlaceObj.class);
            creator_id = a.getName();
            System.out.println("Name:" + creator_id);
            item.put(ITEM_DESTINATION, creator_id);
            itemList.add(item);
        }

        mListAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemList);
        lsv_main.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="10px"
        android:shrinkColumns="0"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/start" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_source"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_destination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/destination" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_destination"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pick_date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pick_time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="2" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat

```
05-18 15:44:22.237 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride I/System.out:  [{"rideId":1,"create_on":"2018-03-07","travel_start_time":"2018-03-07 17:17:00","source_place_id":1,"destination_place_id":2,"seats_offered":2,"creator_id":1,"remark":"music taxi","placeId":1,"name":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court","latitude":22.2882477,"longitude":114.1907985,"address":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court, 5 Fook Yum Rd, Causeway Bay, Hong Kong"},{"rideId":2,"create_on":"2018-03-10","travel_start_time":"2018-03-10 18:54:00","source_place_id":1,"destination_place_id":3,"seats_offered":3,"creator_id":1,"remark":"good as","placeId":1,"name":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court","latitude":22.2882477,"longitude":114.1907985,"address":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court, 5 Fook Yum Rd, Causeway Bay, Hong Kong"}]
    05-18 15:44:22.238 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride I/System.out: {"rideId":1,"create_on":"2018-03-07","travel_start_time":"2018-03-07 17:17:00","source_place_id":1,"destination_place_id":2,"seats_offered":2,"creator_id":1,"remark":"music taxi","placeId":1,"name":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court","latitude":22.2882477,"longitude":114.1907985,"address":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court, 5 Fook Yum Rd, Causeway Bay, Hong Kong"}
    05-18 15:44:22.238 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride I/System.out: Wed Mar 07 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2018
    05-18 15:44:22.240 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride I/System.out: {"rideId":2,"create_on":"2018-03-10","travel_start_time":"2018-03-10 18:54:00","source_place_id":1,"destination_place_id":3,"seats_offered":3,"creator_id":1,"remark":"good as","placeId":1,"name":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court","latitude":22.2882477,"longitude":114.1907985,"address":"Harbour Heights Ko Fung Court, 5 Fook Yum Rd, Causeway Bay, Hong Kong"}
    05-18 15:44:22.241 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride I/System.out: Sat Mar 10 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2018
    05-18 15:44:22.241 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride I/System.out: myArry [fyp.wcm.shareourride.Ride@c945316, fyp.wcm.shareourride.Ride@57c4497]
    05-18 15:44:22.243 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride I/System.out: sourceid: 1
    05-18 15:44:22.249 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                        --------- beginning of crash
    05-18 15:44:22.250 7813-7813/fyp.wcm.shareourride E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: fyp.wcm.shareourride, PID: 7813
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String fyp.wcm.shareourride.PlaceObj.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at fyp.wcm.shareourride.MainActivity.showRide(MainActivity.java:401)
                                                                            at fyp.wcm.shareourride.MainActivity$2$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:212)
                                                                            at fyp.wcm.shareourride.CustomJsonObjectRequest$1.onResponse(CustomJsonObjectRequest.java:25)
                                                                            at fyp.wcm.shareourride.CustomJsonObjectRequest$1.onResponse(CustomJsonObjectRequest.java:22)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6097)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    05-18 15:44:22.252 1622-2345/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity fyp.wcm.shareourride/.MainActivity
    05-18 15:44:22.256 1622-2345/? I/InputDispatcher: Window 'Window{8721876 u0 fyp.wcm.shareourride/fyp.wcm.shareourride.MainActivity}' spent 0.0ms processing input events on average(0/0). Monitor spent 0.0ms processing input events on average(0/0).
    05-18 15:44:22.258 1622-2345/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger
```

- Emulator API Level:23:5554
- Real Device API Level: 24

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: posted. @JyotiJK

Comment: is using sharepreference problem??? @VishalChhodwani

Comment: Please see [What is a NullPointerException and how do I fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: but the object is not null on emulator @vatbub

Comment: You can also debug on a real device. Set a breakpoint right before the line that is causing the NPE and step through your code. That way, you will most probably see why the object is null.

Comment: String json = sharedPreferences.getString("placeObj" + rides.get(i).getSourceID(), "");  the json object become null in real device

Comment: but why the json object is not null in emulator...

Answer (score 0):

There is one feature in API level 24 which is `android:allowBackup`

> Whether to allow the application to participate in the backup and
>   restore infrastructure. If this attribute is set to false, no backup
>   or restore of the application will ever be performed, even by a
>   full-system backup that would otherwise cause all application data to
>   be saved via adb. The default value of this attribute is true.

In short if `android:allowBackup` is true in manifest your Sharedpreferences data will be restored, ie if you logged in and store your `userId` in Sharedpreferences it will remain stored whether you uninstall or install new Application.
So just add `android:allowBackup="false"` you manifest under `<application>` tag.